# How to set -RecipientFilter on New-DynamicDistributionGroup using a variable

Tags: powershell

I am wanting to create some Dynamic Distribution Lists via a csv import. I want the -RecipientFilter to use values from the csv data. So, I am trying to work out the syntax and having no luck. My actual filter will have a few parts but I cannot even get this simple one to work.

Setting the -Name via a variable works fine.

```
$dgName = "AAC"
$dgCode1 = "QQ"

New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name $dgName  -RecipientFilter { ExtensionCustomAttribute1 -eq 'QQ'  }
```

Setting the -RecipientFilter expression does not.

```
New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name $dgName  -RecipientFilter { ExtensionCustomAttribute1 -eq $dgCode1  }
```

as I end up with `'$dgCode1'` in the filter.

I tried Invoke-Expression:

```
$myCommand = "New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name $dgName -RecipientFilter { ExtensionCustomAttribute1 -eq $dgCode1 }"

Invoke-Expression $myCommand
```

but that throws `"Cannot bind parameter 'RecipientFilter' to the target. Exception setting "RecipientFilter": "Invalid filter syntax. For a description of the filter parameter syntax see the command help."`

I have read everything I can find but cannot find a way to do this. I even tried string concatenation:

```
$myCommand = "New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name $dgName  -RecipientFilter { ExtensionCustomAttribute1 -eq " + $dgCode1 + " }"
```

but that still threw the "Invalid Filter Syntax" error.

How can this be done please? I am very new to PowerShell.

Thanks, Murray

**EDIT:** Thanks and Kudos to [@AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings)

A more complete example that works to replicate what I was trying to achieve (line beak for legibility):

```
$dgName = "Class2-3Parents"
$dgCode1 = "P"
$dgSubCode1 = "Class2"
$dgSubCode2 = "Class3"

New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name $dgName -RecipientFilter
"ExtensionCustomAttribute1 -eq '$dgCode1' -and ( ExtensionCustomAttribute2 -eq '$dgSubCode1' -or ExtensionCustomAttribute2 -eq '$dgSubCode2' ) "
```

results in a filter of:

```
((ExtensionCustomAttribute1 -eq 'P') -and (((ExtensionCustomAttribute2 -eq 'Class2') -or (ExtensionCustomAttribute2 -eq 'Class3')))) ...
```

So grateful.
Murray

Comment: This appears to be an issue with using script block notation for a filter. All of the Microsoft help pages show using script blocks (`{}`) for these filters, and it is an incorrect practice usually. See if using `New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name $dgName -RecipientFilter "ExtensionCustomAttribute1 -eq '$dgCode1'"` has better results.

Comment: You Sir, are a genius! Yes! That was it. I obviously need to read up about script blocks to understand the meaning of the syntax and what you wrote. I tested the filter I need to create and all is well. See my question Edit above. :-) :-)

Comment: I edited my question rather than answering it because it seems when I do that the SO moderators delete my posts! Please add you answer so I can accept it. Again, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with using script block notation for a filter. All of the Microsoft help pages show using script blocks (`{}`) for OPATH filters (used by Exchange commands) and Active Directory filters (used by ActiveDirectory module), and it is an incorrect practice because they are not script blocks. The following will have better results.

```
New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name $dgName -RecipientFilter "ExtensionCustomAttribute1 -eq '$dgCode1'"
```

Certain script blocks will have their own scope. That scope won't know anything about variables created outside of the scope.